# Build Tree by Prüfer Code $(6,2,2,6,2,5,10,9,9)$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

I have the Prufer Code  $(6,2,2,6,2,5,10,9,9)$.

I want to build the corresponding tree.

My algorithm:

1)
Tree = $\{\}$, code =  $(6,2,2,6,2,5,10,9,9)$, count = $(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)$

2)
Tree =$\{(2,6)\}$, code = $(2,2,6,2,5,10,9,9)$, count = $(1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)$

3)
Tree =$\{(2,6), (2,3)\}$, code = $(2,6,2,5,10,9,9)$, count = $(1,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)$

4)
Tree =$\{(2,6), (2,3), (2,4)\}$, code = $(6,2,5,10,9,9)$, count = $(1,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)$

5)
Tree =$\{(2,6), (2,3), (2,4),(5,6)\}$, code = $(2,5,10,9,9)$, count = $(1,6,7,8,9,10,11)$

6)
Tree =$\{(2,6), (2,3), (2,4),(5,6), (2,6)\}$, code = $(5,10,9,9)$, count = $(1,7,8,9,10,11)$

7)
Tree =$\{(2,6), (2,3), (2,4),(5,6), (2,6),(5,7)\}$, code = $(10,9,9)$, count = $(1,8,9,10,11)$

8)
Tree =$\{(2,6), (2,3), (2,4),(5,6), (2,6),(5,7),(8,10)\}$, code = $(9,9)$, count = $(1,9,10,11)$

9)
Tree =$\{(2,6), (2,3), (2,4),(5,6), (2,6),(5,7),(8,10),(9,10)\}$, code = $(9)$, count = $(1,9,11)$

10)
Tree =$\{(2,6), (2,3), (2,4),(5,6), (2,6),(5,7),(8,10),(9,10), (9,11)\}$, code = $()$, count = $(1,9)$

11)
Tree = $\{(2,6), (2,3), (2,4),(5,6), (2,6),(5,7),(8,10),(9,10), (9,11),(1,9)\}$

Is my solution correct?

Comment: I do not think your solution is correct. Note that $2$ and $6$ are initially inner nodes, not vertices, since they appear in the Prüfer Code.

Comment: Is there any reason why you unaccepted my answer?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest it goes like this:

Let us first count the degrees of the nodes in the Prüfer Code, ie. count how many times they appear:

$$
\begin{array}{c|c}
\text{node}&6&2&5&10&9\\
\hline
\text{degree}&2&3&1&1&2
\end{array}
$$

Thus $6$ has to have appeared twice as a neighbor of a removed vertex before it could have been removed itself. Similarly $2$ must have three leaves that are removed before it itself becomes a removable leave.

The vertices that can be removed, the free nodes, must be those NOT in the Prüfer Code.

Thus:

```
 T={}, code=(6,2,2,6,2,5,10,9,9), free=(1,3,4,7,8,11)
 T={(1,6)}, code=(2,2,6,2,5,10,9,9), free=(3,4,7,8,11)
 T={(1,6),(3,2)}, code=(2,6,2,5,10,9,9), free=(4,7,8,11)
 T={(1,6),(3,2),(4,2)}, code=(6,2,5,10,9,9), free=(7,8,11)
 T={(1,6),(3,2),(4,2),(7,6)}, code=(2,5,10,9,9), free=(6,8,11)
 T={(1,6),(3,2),(4,2),(7,6),(6,2)}, code=(5,10,9,9), free=(2,8,11)
 T={(1,6),(3,2),(4,2),(7,6),(6,2),(2,5)}, code=(10,9,9), free=(5,8,11)
 T={(1,6),(3,2),(4,2),(7,6),(6,2),(2,5),(5,10)}, code=(9,9), free=(8,10,11)
 T={(1,6),(3,2),(4,2),(7,6),(6,2),(2,5),(5,10),(8,9)}, code=(9), free=(10,11)
 T={(1,6),(3,2),(4,2),(7,6),(6,2),(2,5),(5,10),(8,9),(10,9)}, code=(), free=(9,11)
```

And finally we must connect the remaining two, namely `(9,11)`.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the following algorithm (from [here](http://www-math.ucdenver.edu/%7Ewcherowi/courses/m4408/gtaln7.html)) to generate a spanning tree (on $n$ vertices) of $K_n$, given the corresponding Prüfer sequence (of length $n-2$), since there exists a 1-1 mapping always, in between set of all spanning trees of labeled graph $K_n$ (there are $n^{n-2}$ spanning trees of $K_n$ by Cayley's theorem) and set of all Prüfer sequences of length $n-2$ .

[image]

The following `python` code implements the above algorithm:

```
def get_tree(S):
    n = len(S)
    L = set(range(1, n+2+1))
    tree_edges = []
    for i in range(n):
        u, v = S[0], min(L - set(S))
        S.pop(0)
        L.remove(v)
        tree_edges.append((u,v))
    tree_edges.append((L.pop(), L.pop()))
    return tree_edges
```

Invoking the above function on a Prüfer sequence, we can obtain the corresponding spanning tree of $K_{11}$, as shown below:

```
S = [6,2,2,6,2,5,10,9,9]
T_E = get_tree(S)
```

The next figure shows the final tree:

[image]

The following animation shows the tree-building steps:

[image]